# Java - Calculation

Tags: java, string, math, text, formula

I attempt to write a code that determines the easiness of the text using this equation :

```
Flesch = 206.835 - 1.015(#word/#sentences) - 84.6 (#syllables/#words)
```

My code runs but gives me no result. Can you possibly say where the code is going wrong?

Note that the methods `getNumSentences()`, `getNumWords()`, `getNumSyllables()` are already created and working.

```
public float getFleschScore()
{
    String content = new String();      
    int syllables = getNumSyllables();
    int sentences = getNumSentences();
    int words     = getNumWords();


    //calculate flesch index
    final float f1 = (float) 206.835;
    final float f2 = (float) 84.6;
    final float f3 = (float) 1.015;
    float r1 = (float) syllables / (float) words;
    float r2 = (float) words / (float) sentences;
    float flesch = f1 - (f2*r1) - (f3*r2);

    return flesch;
}
```

Comment: Content is an empty string.  What are those functions operating on?

Comment: Hmm! So the methods read a text and return some int values. Not sure if that's what you're asking about!

Comment: Those methods would be far more general if they were given text.  If you ask them to read text AND calculate words, sentences, syllables then they are doing two things.  That's an object-oriented no-no.  Better to read the content and pass it to the thing that operates on it.  That's why I wrote them as I did in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try writing it more like this:

```
package misc;

/**
 * Created by Michael on 12/11/2015.
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34235423/java-calculation
 */
public class FleschDemo {

    public double getFleschScore(String content) {
        double flesch = 0.0;
        if (!isEmpty(content)) {
            double syllables = (double) getNumSyllables(content);
            double sentences = (double) getNumSentences(content);
            double words = (double) getNumWords(content);
            flesch = 206.835 - 84.6*syllables/words - 1.015*words/sentences;
        }
        return flesch;
    }

    private int getNumWords(String content) {
        int numWords = 0;
        if (!isEmpty(content)) {
            String [] words = content.split("\\s+");
            numWords = words.length;
        }
        return numWords;
    }

    private int getNumSentences(String content) {
        int numSentences = 0;
        if (!isEmpty(content)) {
            // Your implementation here;
        }
        return numSentences;
    }

    public int getNumSyllables(String content) {
        int numSyllables = 0;
        if (!isEmpty(content)) {
            // Your implementation here;
        }
        return numSyllables;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(String content) {
        return (content == null || content.length() == 0);
    }
}
```